# C# system stopping tray application

Tags: c#, windows-xp, restart

I have this C# app which starts at system boot in the tray, and i have the following problem with it, only on Windows XP

I can't restart the PC while the application is running. If I use file > exit, it stops ok and then i can restart. but if i try restarting with the application open, it just won't do it

I tried adding this in the main window constructor, dunno if its the right thing to do:

```
Application.ApplicationExit += new EventHandler(this.OnApplicationExit);
```

and the OnApplicationExit function does the app's shutting down procedure.. but that doesn't help

any ideas?

Comment: This is most likely because the GUI thread is busy doing something. What do you do in the application?

Comment: How do you start your application? by command prompt or throught UI or something else?

Comment: @Joey: I would avoid saying that you should use `TerminateProcess`. It's more of a last resort which you should only use if you really have to since it doesn't allow the process to shut down in an orderly fashion.

Comment: @ho1: I was referring to what Windows does (afaik) when shutting down. Not as an advice what to do yourself.

Comment: @joey: Sorry, I probably misunderstood your previous comment (I can't remember what it said).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you have a `FormClosing` event handler somewhere where you do something like `e.Cancel = true;`?

If so, change it to first look at the close reason to decide if it should cancel or not as:

```
if(e.CloseReason != WindowsShutDown)
     e.Cancel = true;
```

There might be other CloseReasons where you should also not Cancel the closing so might be worth looking at MSDN for that.

Comment: That seemed to solve my problem. I would have never imagine my application could block the entire system. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I've seen this happen before if you've got Cancel = true somewhere in your exit handler.